# I am not able to invoke Fire Fox using Python with selenium library

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

Hello Recently i started working on webautomation i am facing an issue i am not able to invoke my firefox what basically happening i am running .py file through visual studio terminal no error is showing it just simply open command prompt and within fraction of time it close it automatically.
I am using 78.8.0esr version of firefox
here is my code that i have returned.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.google.com"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\AllCodes\\geckodriver.exe")

driver.get(url)
#insert = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
#insert.send_keys("K.J.Somaiya")
button = driver.find_element_by_name("btnK")
button.submit()
# after this new page reload and link are poluated
linktext = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "K. J. Somaiya"))
    ) # Waits 10 second before element loads.

linktext.click()
```

Comment: Add error text and make sure that geco driver and your Fire Fox versions are equal

Comment: @GajJulije Terminal is not showing any error it just simply open command prompt and within fraction of time it close it automatically.